# Always MySQL output nothing. Tell me why?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
    $uname = $_POST["username"]$uname = 
    stripslashes(trim($uname));
    $pward = $_POST["password"];
    $pward = stripcslashes(trim($pward));

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "index_data";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, 
    $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM 00_user_details WHERE 
    username = '$uname'  ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    echo "_".$rows["first_name"]."_";
?>
```

I am a bigger. 
It's my code but it outputs nothing . 
Any if you respected sir/ma'm help me kindly...

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_row()` return enumerated array, use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead to fetch an associative aray

Comment: **Warning:** You are _wide open_ to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: The first line contains an syntax error: `$_POST["username"]$uname = stripslashes(trim($uname));`

Comment: Why are you stripping slashes from the password? If someone included a bunch of slashes in their password, you've just weakened it. All you should do with passwords are hashing them.

Answer (score 1):

Please put semicolon after $_POST["username"] and use mysqli_fetch_assoc in place of mysqli_fetch_row.

mysqli_fetch_assoc return a row as an associative array where the column names will be the keys storing corresponding value.

Please find actual code as below:

```
$uname = $_POST["username"];
$uname = stripslashes(trim($uname));

$pward = $_POST["password"];
$pward = stripcslashes(trim($pward));

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "index_data";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username,$password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM 00_user_details WHERE username = '$uname'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "_".$rows["first_name"]."_";
```